# Problem with solving a system of partial differential equations using the numol function

Tags: mathcad

I'm trying to solve a system of partial differential equations and ran into an error unknown to me. What could it be and how to fix it?
[numol function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15k9v.png)

Tried to change the initial and boundary conditions, nothing happens.